# fetch five characters after a specific string in middle in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, subquery

I have a text field DATA that consist of xml data

data will be like this

```
<XXXXXXX>
<--code-->
<code1>12345<code2>
<XXXXXXX>
<XXXXXXX>
<XXXXXXX>
<XXXXXXX>
<XXXXXXX>
<XXXXXXX>
<XXXXXXX>
<XXXXXXX>
<XXXXXXX>
<XXXXXXX>
```

I need to FETCH  1234 from data it will always be after 
I tried it using substring but it did not worked, I need to fetch that data and need to compare with other column from on other table which is having this code

can someone suggest me the way to do this

Comment: I'm lost.  Is each line a separate row in the table?  Or is this all one long string?  Is the string you want always between those tags?  If not, how is it determined?

Comment: it is a long string ,the above data is of only one column, yes it will be between those tags always

Answer (score 1):

To parse `XML` data use the function `xpath()`, e.g.

```
SELECT (xpath('//code1/text()',xmlcolumn))[1] FROM mytable
```

**Demo**

```
WITH j (col) AS (
  VALUES ('<XXXXXXX><code1>12345</code1></XXXXXXX>'::XML)
) SELECT (xpath('//code1/text()',col))[1] FROM j;

 xpath 
-------
 12345
(1 row)
```

Answer (score 0):

Postges offers `regexp_match()`.  If you want the value between two specific tags in a string column, you can use:

```
select v.*,
       (regexp_match(code, '<code1>([^<]*)<code2>'))[1]
from (values ('<code1>12345<code2>'), ('abcd')) v(code);
```

However, if you are working with XML, you might want to use the native support for XML.  Start with the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-xml.html).